# Where can I get Rabbit card for BTS Skytrain in Bangkok?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, bangkok, bkk

I will be flying to Bangkok and as I understand one of ways to go around that does not require to interact with drivers is to use BTS Skytrain (plus accommodation that I have booked is 5 minute walk from [Bang Na](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Bang+Na+Station/@13.66605,100.5815007,13z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x30e2a013dba51a25:0xedf97029888be19!8m2!3d13.6681306!4d100.6046391) station...)

From what I managed to find on my own, is one needs [Rabbit card](http://www.bts.co.th/customer/en/16-rabbit-step-chg-sky-to-rabbit-type.aspx) to ride Skytrain... however couldn't find anything on where, how much it costs (as I will need 4) do I need any paperwork (or is it just like Oyster)? Is there a counter or machine in Bangkok international airport that sells these cards?

Comment: I found mine on the steps to one of the SkyTrain stations, although I suspect that's not the official way that one is supposed to obtain one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just arrived at Bangkok a few days ago and got the rabbit card.

The station at the airport doesn't sell its card; when I tried to buy it there, a clerk at the counter said you can purchase it only at BTS stations in the city. So I just purchased a single-journey ticket (it is a coin) in cash and then got it in the destination station, which was *Phaya Thai* in my case.

Because I purchased it using my credit card, which requires you to deposit at least 300 Baht, the total price was 380 Baht (80 is an issuing charge). I don't remember the minimum amount of charges in cash, but it is around 100 to 200 Baht (including the charge).

Note that if you want to get on MRT too, you must obtain the different card in Bangkok. The price of the card is 150 Baht, only in cash.

Comment: Hi Blaszard, thanks for the answer, I see so Metro uses one card and BTS uses the other... My plan is to ride to Phaya Thai in SRT-City (brown line)... I guess this solves it... In regards to metro card - cash in USD or THB?

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius Cash in THB. However, the two cards plan to be united into one single card in 2017, so don't get disappointed to see you need only one card soon.

Comment: @Blaszard - have you been in Thailand long?  Here "in 2017" means more like "maybe 2018, but 2019 for sure" 

Comment: @Tom Yeah I know it. In fact IIRC 2017 itself is already a procrastinated schedule...

Comment: It might be worth noting that one doesn't _need_ a Rabbit Card or Metro Card to ride the skytrain and metro - cash ticket machines exist at all stations. The biggest benefit of the cards is that you skip the ticket lines, which can be quite long at peak hours. Also, you get a 10% discount at McDonalds by paying with your Rabbit card ;)